# Keeping track of user ID with custom authentication

Tags: sql, authentication, plsql, session-variables, oracle-apex

I am currently making an app on apex.oracle.com, and I've been trying to solve this for a couple hours now, but I have no idea how to.

Alright, so basically my application has custom authentication based on a user table I created inside of my application. Therefore, it seems to render useless most `APEX_UTIL` functions to retrieve info on the current user. The issue is, I am trying to find a way to store the user's numeric ID from my table in the session, so I could retrieve it directly in the queries throughout my application, in order to do something like `WHERE id = :MEMBER_ID` instead of `WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER(:APP_USER)`.

Now, the way I attempted to do this is by creating a Post Authentication procedure that retrieves the user ID based on the username, and stores that value in the session using `APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE( p_name => 'MEMBER_ID', p_value => member_id )`. However, it seems that `SET_SESSION_STATE` is unable to create custom session values or something, returning an `ERR-1002` every time I use a value name that isn't specifically mentioned in the documentation.

I am a total newbie to APEX so I am probably unaware of something, however I have done many searches, but I could not find anything specifically related to my issue.

Thanks a lot if you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to store a value into an item, whether page or application level. This requires that the item with that name exists in one of those scopes. So, do you have an item somewhere that is called `MEMBER_ID`?
I'd suggest you create one in the application scope. Go through Shared Components > Application items. Once created, you should be able to assign a value either through `apex_util.set_session_state` or with bind variable syntax eg `:MEMBER_ID := somevariable;`

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I ended up using, as someone suggested to me on the Oracle forums. I didn't know about Application items prior.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you can do this. Some have already been suggested in other answers.

1. **Application Item** (as per Tom's answer)
2. **PL/SQL package global** (as per hol's answer) - although you'd have to reset it for each call (e.g. by adding code to the application's Security Attribute **Initialization PL/SQL Code** and clearing it by adding code to **Cleanup PL/SQL Code**).
3. **Globally Accessible Context** - this method, while a little more complex, has some benefits especially for security and debugging. I've described it here: http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2013/02/28/apex-and-application-contexts/, but basically:

   1. Create a globally accessible context:

      ```
      CREATE OR REPLACE CONTEXT MY_CONTEXT USING MY_PACKAGE ACCESSED GLOBALLY;
      ```
   2. In the post-authentication procedure (in the database package `MY_PACKAGE`), you can store the data you wish to keep track of, e.g.

      ```
      DBMS_SESSION.set_context
        (namespace => 'MY_CONTEXT'
        ,attribute => 'MEMBER_ID'
        ,value     => '12345whatever'
        ,client_id =>  v('APP_USER') || ':' || v('APP_SESSION'));
      ```

      (note the caveats in my blog article and the subsequent comments from others about CLIENT_IDENTIFIER not being reliably set at the post-auth stage)
   3. In your views, code, etc. you can access the MEMBER_ID by simply referring to `SYS_CONTEXT('MY_CONTEXT','MEMBER_ID')`.

Comment: Very complete answer! Hadn't really thought of setting package variables using the initialization plsql code myself, but I'm not sure if I'd ever go that route unless I'd be forced to (for package variables I mean). The application item or the context are, in my opinion, more than sufficient.

Comment: The Initialization / Cleanup PL/SQL Code is useful but it needs to be treated with a bit of caution as it is run once for *every single call* to the database - i.e. every page request. Personally I prefer using application items or contexts.